# Deep Saute Pan vs Stockpot

Tags: stock, pan, sauteing, pot

I'm considering some new cookware and some sites have recommended I get a deep saute pan and a stock pot.

But from looking at All Clad's choices for the [stockpot](https://www.macys.com/shop/product/all-clad-stainless-steel-6-qt.-covered-stockpot?ID=570998&CategoryID=7552) and the [deep saute pan](https://www.macys.com/shop/product/all-clad-stainless-steel-6-qt.-covered-ultimate-deep-saute-pan?ID=570996), these seem very similar, except the pan has a long handle and the pot does not.

Is there a functional difference?

[image: deep saute pan]
[image: stockpot]

Comment: What do you currently own in terms of pots?

Comment: A big 8 quart pot with a strainer

Comment: I would go with deep saute, though there are more shallow versions.  Mine has maybe a 3" side.  I use it for risotto, for example.

Comment: From what I can see from the links, they are the same pans, same size, same construction .. different handles

Answer (score 1):

There is no functional difference, just a matter of preference. Pots are pots, in this case. Same material and essentially the same size.